# Newest Spotify update: Autohotkeys script broke

Tags: autohotkey, spotify

I used to use the AutoHotKey script for Spotify shortcuts (the built in shortcuts are limited and only work if the app is in focus, I usually keep it in the background at work).

Anyway, it's updated a million times before with no problem.. but I downloaded the latest spotify update and it no longer works. Any idea why?

Here's the script.

```html
#z::Run www.autohotkey.com

SetTitleMatchMode 2 

; "CTRL + LEFT"  for previous 
^Left:: 
{
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^{Left}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
}


; "CTRL + RIGHT"  for next 
^Right:: 
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^{Right}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
} 

; "CTRL + UP"  for pause
^UP::
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, {space}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
} 

; "CTRL + DOWN"  for info 
^Down:: 
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
SetTitleMatchMode 2 
WinGetTitle, now_playing, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
StringTrimLeft, playing, now_playing, 10 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
clipboard = %playing%`r`n
return 
} 

; "CTRL + PAGE UP"  for volume up
^PgUP::
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^{Up}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
} 

; "CTRL + PAGE DOWN"  for volume down
^PgDn::
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^{Down}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
} 

; "CTRL + END"  for mute
^End::
{ 
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
ControlSend, ahk_parent, ^+{Down}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow 
DetectHiddenWindows, Off 
return 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Hotkey for next song in Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957636/hotkey-for-next-song-in-spotify) - includes a statement from a Spotify developer, as well as a statement that it will be fixed in the upcoming version, as well as a workaround for the moment:

```
^Left::Media_Prev
```